# convert curl command to php curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to convert the following curl command to php curl

```
curl -k -u username:pass https://HOSTNAME/something/some.dll\?GetSomeInfo\&Items\=getSomeRequest\;getSomeInfoRequest
```

The curl commands work fine in linux. The php code I wrote below prints nothing. If I remove the CURLOPT_USERPWD line, it prints a failed authentication page. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Right now I have this:

```
$username='username';
$password='pass';
$location= escapeshellcmd('https://HOSTNAME/something/some.dll\?GetSomeInfo\&Items\=getSomeRequest\;getSomeInfoRequest');
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$location);
echo curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: After the call to `curl_exec`, what does `curl_error()` return?  It seems like you're mangling your `$location` variable with lots of unnecessary backslashes as well.  Try it without the backslashes and without the `shellescapecmd`.

Comment: I removed the backslashes and escapeshellcmd. It still prints nothing. also curl_error prints nothing. I printed curl_error($ch); after curl_exec();

Comment: I eneded up doing  
shell_exec('curl -k -u username:pass https:// host/something/some.dll\?GetSomeInfo\&Items\=getSomeRequest\;getSomeInfoRequest')